# Process multi get request from diffrent php files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to process multi get request from multi php files. In this scenario `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ single-product.php?view_product=$1 [NC,L]` part is working fine but `RewriteRule ^m(.*)/?$ menu-products.php?view_menu=$1 [NC,L]` part not works. Any solution?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ single-product.php?view_product=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^m(.*)/?$ menu-products.php?view_menu=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Also provide your original urls and required urls example.

Answer (score 0):

The second rule never runs because the first one matches it. Swap them:

```
RewriteRule ^m(.*)/?$ menu-products.php?view_menu=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ single-product.php?view_product=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not works! problem is the example.com/m/$variable when i use it my page content not slows from database. i get blank page without any error